# Graphs with rational eigenvalues

Tags: graph-theory, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, spectral-graph-theory, adjacency-matrix

Let $A$ be the adjacency matrix of a graph with eigenvalues $\lambda_i$. My questions are:

- Is there any assumption/conditions for a graph to have all rational eigenvalues ($\lambda_i \in \mathbb{Q} \;\forall i$)?
- Could you introduce graphs which can satisfy the above condition? (You may say about a specific application)

Of course, you may consider the case all eigenvalues are integers. Any discussion on the topic above is useful.

---

The question is edited based on the nice comment of @ChrisGodsil.

Answer (score 3):

Given an adjacency matrix $A$, the characteristic polynomial of $A$ will always have leading coefficient $1$, and in particular its roots will be algebraic integers. Hence if an eigenvalue $\lambda$ of $A$ satisfies $\lambda \in \mathbb{Q}$, then necessarily $\lambda \in \mathbb{Z}$, as the rational algebraic integers are precisely the integers. So your question is really about graphs with *integer* eigenvalues.

These are called integral graphs. The problem of characterising precisely which graphs are integral is incredibly difficult, and wide open -- it was first raised in 1974 by Harary and Schwenk in [Harary, Frank; Schwenk, Allen J.
*Which graphs have integral spectra?* Graphs and combinatorics (Proc. Capital Conf., George Washington Univ., Washington, D.C., 1973), pp. 45–51. Lecture Notes in Math., Vol. 406, Springer, Berlin, 1974.].

They note that the problem seems very intractable. Some good surveys on the topic exist -- see for example the survey by [Wang](https://research.utwente.nl/en/publications/a-survey-of-results-on-integral-trees-and-integral-graphs) or [Balińska et al](https://www.jstor.org/stable/43666564?seq=1).

Answer (score 1):

There exist lots of easy examples, even looking only at integers :

- Complete graph $K_n$ with eigenvalues $\{(n-1)^1,-1^{n-1}\}$
- Complete bipartite graphs $K_{m,n}$ have spectrum $\{\pm \sqrt{mn},0^{n+m-2}\}$. With appropriate values for $m$ $n$ you can have integers values
- The cycle graph $C_n$ has spectrum $\{2cos\frac{2k\pi}{n},k=0,\ldots,n-1\}$ so that $C_3$, $C_4$ and $C_6$ have integer eigenvalues
- The petersen graph has eigenvalues $\{3,1^5,-2^4\}$

However, I doubt that you can find general result for graph with rational eigenvalues. This is because it is very to build such a graph. If a graph $G$ have $\lambda_i$ for eigenvalues, then :

1. If $G$ is regular, its complement its also regular, and the other eigenvalues are $-1-\lambda_i$
2. If $G$ is $r$-regular with characteristic polynomial $\phi(G,x)$, then its line graph has for characteristic polynomial $$\phi(L(G),x)=(x+2)^{m-n}\phi(G,x+2-r)$$ so that its eigenvalues are also integers

But more importantly perhaps, if you have two graphs $G$ and $H$ with eigenvalues $\lambda_i$ and $\mu_j$, then their cartesian product $G\times H$ has eigenvalues $\lambda_i + \mu_j$.
It is therefore quite easy to build a graph with integer eigenvalues.

I might be wrong, I never looked at the actual problem. This is only my (strong) intuition.

Comment: If an eigenvalue of a graph is rational, then that eigenvalue is necessarily an integer. So "even looking only at integers" is no restriction at all.